# How do I call the top ancestor method

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

I have a class which inherits from a class which inherits from a class (and a few more in the original code :)).

How do I call from an override to one of the top most parents?
Here is a code sample:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Animal a = new Animal();
        a.DoSomething();
        Predator p = new Predator();
        p.DoSomething();
        Cat c = new Cat();
        c.DoSomething();
    }
}

class Animal
{
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Animal");
    }
}

class Predator : Animal
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Predator");
    }
}

class Cat : Predator
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        base.DoSomething();
        //Console.WriteLine("Cat");
    }
}
```

I want that when I call c.DoSomething() method I will get "Animal" as a result.

Thanks to all

Comment: There's no built in way to do it. What most people would do is expose a protected method in `Predator` that calls `base.DoSomething`.

Comment: it's a duplicate of about a dozen other questions; search for 'base.base' or 'grandparent'

Comment: Thanks Michael Edenfield. I`ll search for these keywords.

Comment: Thanks mike z. I`ll go for your work method.